# Problem overriding MagePlaza OSC 3rd party .html file

Tags: magento2.3

I want to override this file but everything I have tried does not work.

/app/code/Mageplaza/Osc/view/frontend/web/template/container/payment.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy "payment.html" file from

> /app/code/Mageplaza/Osc/view/frontend/web/template/container/payment.html

and override it in your theme on below path

> /app/code/Design/Frontend/Your/Theme/Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/payment.html

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Comment: great. happy to hear this. ans yes, mark it as solution so other can found exact answer

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/payment.html': 
              'Namespace_Module/template/container/payment.html'
        }
  }
};
```

**After run the magento commands.**

Answer (score 0):

***it's simple put file below path***

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Mageplaza_Osc/web/template/container/payment.html
```